# Error with Bulkloading from CSV to PostGres

Tags: psycopg2, pygrametl

```
 import pandas
 import pygrametl
 import psycopg2
 from pygrametl.tables import SlowlyChangingDimension,CachedDimension,BulkDimension
 from pygrametl.datasources import CSVSource


 ##Connection to PostGres
 connection = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="postgres", user="postgres", 
 password="tekihcan")
 connect = pygrametl.ConnectionWrapper(connection)

def pgcopybulkloader(name, atts, fieldsep, rowsep, nullval, filehandle):
 # Here we use driver-specific code to get fast bulk loading.
 # You can change this method if you use another driver or you can
 # use the FactTable or BatchFactTable classes (which don't require
 # use of driver-specifc code) instead of the BulkFactTable class.
  global connection
  curs = connect.cursor()
  try:
       curs.copy_from(file=filehandle, table=name, sep=fieldsep,
                columns=atts,null='null')
  except(Exception, psycopg2.Database) as error:
       print("Error %s" % error)       

date_dim = BulkDimension(name='date_dim',key='d_date_sk',attributes=[
               'd_date_id (B)'
               ,'d_date'
               ,'d_month_seq'
               ,'d_week_seq'
               ,'d_quarter_seq'
               ,'d_year'
               ,'d_dow'
               ,'d_moy'
               ,'d_dom'
               ,'d_qoy'
               ,'d_fy_year'
               ,'d_fy_quarter_seq'
               ,'d_fy_week_seq'
               ,'d_day_name'
               ,'d_quarter_name'
               ,'d_holiday'
               ,'d_weekend'
               ,'d_following_holiday'
               ,'d_first_dom'
               ,'d_last_dom'
               ,'d_same_day_ly'
               ,'d_same_day_lq'
               ,'d_current_day'
              ,'d_current_week'
              ,'d_current_month'
              ,'d_current_quarter'
              ,'d_current_year'
              ],lookupatts = ['d_date_id (B)'],
              bulkloader = pgcopybulkloader)

              date_dim_source = CSVSource(open('C:/Users/HP\Documents/v2.13.0rc1/data/date_dim.csv', 
              'r', 16384),delimiter='|')

    def main():
     for row in date_dim_source:
        date_dim.insert(row)
```

The code is failing with error -

As per my understanding the error is caused because the target table is empty. The CSV source doesn't have header as well. Could this be impacting the code?
Please find the link that was used to develop the code - https://chrthomsen.github.io/pygrametl/

[image: Output 1]

[image: Output 2]

Comment: I'm not seeing an error, just parts of a traceback. The error message should be at the end of the traceback. FYI, please don't post images, use copy and paste to post text. The target table being empty is pretty standard, so not an an issue.  Same for no header as the header row is ignored on input anyway.

Comment: My apologies the issue was resolved when I restarted kernel